# passenger / website under heavy load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

running passenger v 5.0.11 on ubuntu, behind nginx, with ruby 2.1.3p242

The app is doing a concurrent call (generate a pdf file via whthlktopdf, opening the app one some url and saving it to a file) when a specific model is updated

not saying this is a good pattern, thing is the call get stuck and the passenger process reaches its passenger_max_request_queue_size

hence I'm wondering if there would be a way to kill stuck processes automatically when this kind of thing occurs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a builtin feature for that: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_max_request_time

Comment: available passenger entreprise though